# Deserialization and serialization using newtonsoft c#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, json.net

My application is binding a REST API, that returns this to me:

```
{
    key: "XXXX-XXXX",
    fields: {
        customfield_10913: {
             value: "L2"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using Newtonsoft JSON to serialize and deserialize and I've created these models to make it work:

```
public class Issue
{
    [JsonProperty("key")]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("fields")]
    public Fields Fields { get; set; }
}

public class Fields
{
    [JsonProperty("customfield_10913")]
    public CustomField Level { get; set; }
}

public class CustomField
{
   [JsonProperty("value")]
   public string Value{ get; set; }   
}
```

The application is deserializing everything ok, using this code:

```
T model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(result);
```

After a lot of business logic, my WEB API should return a new JSON:

```
protected T Get()
{
    return model;
}
```

And I've got everything like the JSON I've read from another API. 
So, What I need?

- I need to read the field **CUSTOM_FIELDXXX**, but I can't return it with this name in my WEB API. How could I read this field, but when I'm doing the serialization, it assume another one?

Comment: You need to read this class, do something and return it with te custom_fieldXXX renamed? (The question isn't 100% clear to me) 
If that is the case you can create another set of classes with the correct fieldnames.

Answer (score 1):

You may try below function

```
Issue model = deserializeObject<Issue>(result);

public T deserializeObject<T>(string result)
        {
            try
            {
                var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
                    NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore,
                    DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore
                };
                var items = (T)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result, typeof(T), settings);

                return items;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can have any property name for your `CustomField` property, you can serialize that as a [`Dictionary<string, CustomField>`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeDictionary.htm), like so:

```
public class Issue
{
    public Issue()
    {
        this.Fields = new Dictionary<string, CustomField>();
    }

    [JsonProperty("key")]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("fields")]
    public Dictionary<string, CustomField> Fields { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use any string-valued name for your custom field.

Working [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kYL6dn).